# Css problem on Ie9 ( not beta version )

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have this simple code in css:

```
#main {
    height: 100%; 
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color:black;
    overflow: auto;

}
```

and this simple html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Benvenuti in Egnomia</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./prova.css">
<body>
<div id="main">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If i resize the window ie 9 scroll bar doesn't work, the min-height (also for width ) are not matched.

Why? On chrome, firefox and all others work fine!!

Comment: What does "overflow: auto;" do? Try to remove

Comment: It does seem to work if you set height to pixel value. Don't know why it doesn't work with percentage. I did set html and body tags to be 100%, but that did nothing if main div has height set as percentage.

Comment: Also search for "min-height ie" turns up a number of hacks and they do add min-height effect (adding scrollbar upon minimizing the browser), but they seem to ignore 100% height.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the HTML5 Doctype this problem is fixed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Benvenuti in Egnomia</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./prova.css">
<body>
<div id="main">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

IE9 renders websites using a compatibility mode unless a doctype is detected.

Actually if you add the html5 doctype the behaviour is just consistent across the browsers, it doesn't do what you originally set out to do.

To fix entirely add this to the CSS file

```
html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```